# How can I create an app occupying half of my Android phone screen in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I need to build an app in Flutter. I doesn't want the app to fully occupy the screen. I am attaching the kind of output I want, the bottom portion is my app and instead of the Amazon logo, I would like to have the phone's background UI, the wallpaper and list of apps. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

The kind of output I want, the bottom portion is supposed to be my app[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr9EE.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I have no experience writing flutter what so ever, but you are probably looking for a BottomSheet component

Answer (score 1):

if you want your app to occupy only half space of the screen then you just need to give this as the height of the parent container:

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height \ 2
```

Comment: So by doing this, would I be able to keep the rest of screen, phone's UI as it is?

Comment: Yup or you can just use two containers in column and wrap both of them with expanded widget. They'll both occupy half space of the screen.

Comment: Thanks it worked partially, the app got reduced to the upper half, what extra do I need to add to take it to the lower half?

Comment: for that I've to see your code that how placed the widgets but I would recommend you to use column and place your containers in it and wrap them with expanded widget so that the'll both take half half space of the screen. Do read more about column and expanded widgets.